# The Badges are not being awarded

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

It's been 11 hours after the site came out and up to now the badges are not being awarded to the users (Please ignore the informed badge that's a different case in this case).

For example the badges, Autobiography,
Supporter, and Teacher should of been rewarded hours ago.

Comment: Does this issue still persist?

Comment: I was just awarded a bunch of badges...thinking y'all fixed it? It did persist up until yesterday.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue has since been resolved

Comment: @Ethan is that the normal procedure on meta, or does staff usually add a tag saying that it has been resolved?

Comment: @selene I completely forgot about the tags. A staff member shout add the [tag:status-completed] tag.